# How can one batch file get the exit code of another?

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp

I have two batch files, `task.bat` and `runtask.bat`. The `runtask.bat`calls `task.bat`and I would like `runtask.bat` to get the exit code of `task.bat` into a variable. How could this be done?

**task.bat:**

```
@echo off
set errorlevel=1
```

**runtask.bat**

```
...
CMD /C task.bat
set taskexitcode=????
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just swap `CMD /C` for `call`.

***task.bat:***

```
@echo off
set errorlevel=15
```

***runtask.bat***

```
call task.bat
set taskexitcode=%errorlevel%
echo %taskexitcode%
```

***Output***

```
15
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. It also allows variables to be set in `task.bat` and read in `runtask.bat`. Thanks very much!

Comment: Great, no worries. I didn't actually know about the variables, nice :)

Comment: The exit command has an `/B` switch for setting the exit code for a batch script.

Comment: @william-bettridge-radford: `/B` determines whether `exit` terminates the script or `cmd.exe` also. It has nothing to do with the exit code.

Comment: `EXIT /?` lists `EXIT /B [exitCode]`; it sets an exit code and returns from the subroutine or script.

Answer (score 4):

I had a batch script in Teamcity pipeline and it did not exit after it's child script did exit with code 1.

To fix the problem I added this string `IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT 1` after the child script call.

**main-script.bat**

```
...some code
call child-script.bat
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT 1
...some code
```

After the child script call, exit result is save to `%ERRORLEVEL%`. If it did exit with error the value would be not equal to 0. So we check this and if it is the case we exit with code 1 (error).

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct, but if you are using `call` to call another batch script, and that second batch script is using `SetLocal`, you may need to use a parsing trick to accomplish this. If you are running into this, add the following code before your `exit b`:

```
ENDLOCAL&set myvariable=%myvariable%
```

Now the value of `myvariable` is made available to the calling context and you can see the value in the other script.

References:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16167938/89590
http://www.borngeek.com/2008/05/22/exiting-batch-file-contexts/